# Trying to set up the PIT using IRQ 0 results in what seems to be a triple fault

Tags: c, assembly, interrupt, osdev, irq

I am trying to develop a simple interrupt-driven OS in the C Language for x86. I have just installed an IDT, set up some ISRs (which seem to be working fine, I tested by printing 6/0) and I am now on the stage where I am setting up some IRQs. The problem that seems to be occurring here is.. well.. nothing happens. Let me go step by step on everything I have done so far so maybe we can identify the problem.

**Step 1 - Set up and load the IDT**

I know that each entry in the IDT is composed of some offset bits, a code segment selector, a zero entry, a type attribute, and some more offset bits. Because of this, my typedef for `idtdesc_t` looks like this

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t low;
    uint16_t sel;
    uint8_t null;
    uint8_t tattr;
    uint16_t high;
} __attribute__((packed)) idtdesc_t;
```

I know that the IDT is loaded using the `lidt` instruction, so I need to make a pointer type that is loadable by that instruction. With that in mind, here is the typedef I use for the IDT pointer

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t lim;
    uint32_t base;
} __attribute__((packed)) idtptr_t;
```

This is all still in my idt.h header file. Finally, to be manipulated by the code itself, I made these two variables

```
idtptr_t idtr;
idtdesc_t idt[256];
```

And the functions to set the IDT gates and to clear the IDT look like this

```
uint8_t idt_install()
{
    idtr.base = &idt;
    idtr.lim = (sizeof (idtdesc_t) * 256) - 1;

    for(size_t i = 0; i<256; i++) {
        idt[i].low = 0;
        idt[i].high = 0;
        idt[i].null = 0;
        idt[i].sel  = 0;
        idt[i].tattr = 0;
    }

    idt_load();

    return 0;
}

void idt_setentry(uint8_t num, uint32_t base, uint16_t sel, uint8_t tattr)
{
    idt[num].low = (base & 0xFFFF);
    idt[num].high = (base >> 16) & 0xFFFF;

    idt[num].null = 0;
    idt[num].sel = sel;
    idt[num].tattr = tattr;
}
```

Just for reference, my `idt_load` function is defined in a file called `idt.asm` like this

```
extern idtr
global idt_load

idt_load:
       lidt[idtr]
       ret
```

Now that this is done, we are ready to move on to step 2.


**Step 2 - Write some ISR stubs and an ISR handler**

Now, I need to write an ISR handler and some ISR stubs. I do it like this in a file called `isr.asm`

```
global isr0
...
global isr30
global isr31

extern handler

isr0:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 0
    jmp isr_stub
...
isr30:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 30
    jmp isr_stub
isr31:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 31
    jmp isr_stub

isr_stub:
    pusha
    push ds
    push es
    push fs
    push gs
    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov eax, esp
    push eax
    mov eax, handler
    call eax
    pop eax
    pop gs
    pop fs
    pop es
    pop ds
    popa
    add esp, 8
    iret
```

Some of these ISRs push an error code, so I have pushed an error code for some of the ones that are not shown. I have a `handler` function in my C file, as one is used in the Assembly function. It takes a pointer to a `regs_t` typed variable called `r`, which represents the stack frame. The definition for `regs_t` looks like this

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t gs, fs, es, ds;
    uint32_t edi, esi, ebp, esp, ebx, edx, ecx, eax;
    uint32_t int_no, err_code;
    uint32_t eip, cs, eflags, useresp, ss;
} regs_t;
```

So with all that said, here is my `handler` function

```
void handler(regs_t *r)
{
    if(r->int_no < 32) {
        terminal_puterr(emsgs[r->int_no], r->int_no);
        for(;;);
    }
}
```

And of course, I need to remap the ISRs (most of it taken out for compactness) as well.

```
uint8_t isr_install()
{
    idt_setentry(0, (unsigned) isr0, 0x08, 0x8E);
    idt_setentry(1, (unsigned) isr1, 0x08, 0x8E);
    ...
    idt_setentry(30, (unsigned) isr30, 0x08, 0x8E);
    idt_setentry(31, (unsigned) isr31, 0x08, 0x8E);
    return 0;
}
```

Once I switched to GNU make, the handler catches(d) the right exceptions when they are called in `kmain()`. Now, the problematic parts begin... once I load my IRQs in a very similar way, the CPU just triple faults. The only handler I have is the `timer` handler. Here is my code, starting with irq.asm

```
global irq0
...
global irq15

extern handler_irq

irq0:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 32
    jmp irq_stub
...
irq15:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 47
    jmp irq_stub
irq_stub:
    pusha
    push ds
    push es
    push fs
    push gs
    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov eax, esp
    mov eax, handler_irq
    call eax
    pop eax
    pop gs
    pop fs
    pop es
    pop ds
    popa
    add esp, 8
    iret
```

And my irq.c, which contains my handlers and the remapping code

```
#include <irq.h>

void *irq_routines[16] = {
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
};

void irq_install_handler(int irq, void (*handler)(regs_t *r))
{
    irq_routines[irq] = handler;
}

void irq_remove_handler(int irq)
{
    irq_routines[irq] = 0;
}

void irq_remap(void)
{
    outb(0x20, 0x11);
    outb(0xA0, 0x11);
    outb(0x21, 0x20);
    outb(0xA1, 0x28);
    outb(0x21, 0x04);
    outb(0xA1, 0x02);
    outb(0x21, 0x01);
    outb(0xA1, 0x01);
    outb(0x21, 0x0);
    outb(0xA1, 0x0);
}

void handler_irq(regs_t *r)
{
    void (*handler) (regs_t *r);
    handler = irq_routines[r->int_no - 32];

    if(handler) {
        handler(r);
    }

    if(r->int_no >= 40) {
        outb(0xA0, 0x20);
    }

    outb(0x20, 0x20);
}

void irq_install()
{
    irq_remap();
    idt_setentry(32, (unsigned)irq0, 0x08, 0x8E);
    ...
    idt_setentry(47, (unsigned)irq15, 0x08, 0x8E);
}
```

And finally, I mapped a timer handler to IRQ 0 (for now, the code is from James Molloy's Kernel Development Tutorials)

```
#include <timer.h>

uint32_t tick = 0;

static void timer_callback(regs_t *r)
{
   tick++;
   terminal_puts("Tick: ");
   terminal_putint(tick);
   terminal_puts("\n");
}

void timer_install(uint32_t frequency)
{
   // Firstly, register our timer callback.
   irq_install_handler(0, &timer_callback);

   // The value we send to the PIT is the value to divide it's input clock
   // (1193180 Hz) by, to get our required frequency. Important to note is
   // that the divisor must be small enough to fit into 16-bits.
   uint32_t divisor = 1193180 / frequency;

   // Send the command byte.
   outb(0x43, 0x36);

   // Divisor has to be sent byte-wise, so split here into upper/lower bytes.
   uint8_t l = (uint8_t)(divisor & 0xFF);
   uint8_t h = (uint8_t)( (divisor>>8) & 0xFF );

   // Send the frequency divisor.
   outb(0x40, l);
   outb(0x40, h);
}
```

But, when I try to install this handler in kmain.c, it results in a Triple Fault and not even my ISR handlers working anymore. Here is the code in kmain.c

```
#include <kernel.h>

void kmain(void)
{
    interrupt_disable();
    terminal_init(LGREEN, BLACK);

    idt_install();
    irq_install();
    interrupt_enable();

    terminal_puts("Hello, refined world!\n");
    terminal_puts("This is a kernel\n");
    terminal_puts("Working or not?\n");

    timer_install(50);

    while(1) {asm volatile ("cli"); asm volatile ("hlt");};
}
```

I have been struggling with this for days. What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

P.S: some people suggesting getting rid of the "cli" at the end, but it just did the same and also resulted in a Triple Fault.

Comment: Are you using a mutiboot loader? If so, have you set up your own GDT?

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes, I have

Comment: What is the `pop eax` for here `call eax` `pop eax`? Seems you are popping off a value that didn't have a corresponding push. Just above the call this looks unusual `mov eax, esp
    mov eax, handler_irq` .  You put esp in EAX and then immediately overwite it with handler_irq. If I had to guess this code was meant to be `push esp` 
    `mov eax, handler_irq` `call eax` `pop eax` . The idea is that _ESP_ is pushed as the first parameter to the handler which is effectively a pointer to the interrupt frame. The `pop eax` is just fix up the stack to account for the `push esp`

Comment: Long story short replace `mov eax, esp` with `push esp`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch still does not work for some reason

Comment: If you are not doing so I suggest running this in bochdbg or some other system emulator that lets you step through and examine state, look at what it thinks the interrupts point at.

Comment: I have to agree with @SoronelHaetir . Bochs in particular is the best tool to usually examine what it happening especially with interrupts. You are able to dump the IDT to make sure it is valid and set up as expected. You can also find where it faults.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Stepping through it, the OS never gets past the first line of kmain.c

Comment: @MichaelPetch I wanted to say the same to you too.. it doesn't let me step past the first line of kmain.c, just jumps back when I type 'continue' into gdb. I don't know how a bochsrc is written, so I am researching that now

Comment: I recommended bochs. But outside the code you posted here you might want to look at your gdt_load function. I noticed it is missing something important.

Comment: Also remember to get rid of the division by zero you do in `kmain`. You don't handle that exception so it will fault since you didn't install a handler for it.

Comment: And if you haven't seen it yet `load_gdt` is missing a `ret` instruction.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It seems to be working now (as in the Triple Fault stops). But, now, nothing happens...

Comment: To make this easier to debug, instead of enabling the timer interrupt (with `interrupt_enable`), I suggest you use int 0x20 so you get one interrupt to debug instead of a stream of them.

Comment: Do you see your messages ("This is a kernel", etc.)?

Comment: If you are past the fault you should probably debug your interrupt handler. You'll likely find an issue there.

Comment: @Michael, where do you see load_gdt?

Comment: @Michael, you mentioned there is no handler for divide by 0, but isn't there a handler for every exception < 32 (once idt_install has completed)?

Comment: @prl Because I looked at his git repo that he posted in a previous question lol

Comment: @MichaelPetch I did install them at isr.c, where it's one handler and it switches through and prints the interrupt number. I added the ret. I do see my messages now

Comment: The code for isr_install is there, but @Michael may be right that it is never called.

Comment: You definitely want to call isr_install, so you get a message when an unexpected exception occurs.

Comment: @SafalAryal : You may have created a function called `isr_install` but you never called it from `kmain`

Comment: @prl Oops! I called it, and I can now handle expections

Comment: @MichaelPetch I guess the timer handler is now an issue that needs to be fixed.

Comment: you should set a breakpoint on the interrupt handler and step through it.

Comment: You might ask yourself _Where do I call `timer_install`_

Comment: once you make a call to timer_install somewhere then you might consider removing the infinite loop in `handler`. And once you do that get rid of the `cli` in the infinite loop that you have at the end of `kmain`. Since you enabled interrupts you want to keep them enabled in the infinite loop. the `hlt` instruction is designed to hlt until the next interrupt. If you turn them off  you won't get them.

Comment: `timer.h` has the wrong prototype for `timer_install` . It takes a frequency parameter. In the header you have `void timer_install();` but the actual function is `void timer_install(uint32_t frequency)`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have fixed all the problems! I now have a simple interrupt based keyboard I/O driver!

Comment: @SafalAryal so please write an answer :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Will do!

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ok!